# Pandas rolling apply to update the Series for next iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have following Series s, I want to rolling apply a self-defined function "test", and immediately update the results to s so that the next iteration of "test" is based on the updated s. Let me walk you through my example:

```
s = pd.Series(range(5), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5))
s 
2000-01-01    0
2000-01-02    1
2000-01-03    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
Freq: D, dtype: int32
```

My self-defined function as below. This is just a simplified example of my real case. We can see during the first iteration, the returned variable 'update' is set to 100, and I want the s to be updated as [0, 1, 100, 3, 4,....]. For the next iteration, the arr.sum() will calculated based on (1+100+3) instead of (1+2+3).

```
def test(arr):
    print(arr)
    print(arr.sum())
    if arr.sum()%3==0:
        print('True')
        update=100
    else:
        update=arr[-1]
    return update
s=s.rolling(window=3).apply(test)

[ 0.  1.  2.]
3.0
True
[ 1.  2.  3.]
6.0
True
[ 2.  3.  4.]
9.0
True
```

Ideal output:

```
[ 0.  1.  2.]
3.0
True

'Update s with 100'
[ 1.  100.  3.]
104

[ 100.  3.  4.]
107
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dataframe.rolling is operating on the original dataframe only, it actually provides a rolling transformation. If any data is modified in a rolling window of the dataframe, it will NOT be updated in the consequential rolling windows.

Actually I am facing the same issue here. So far the alternative I am using is to manually loop through each rolling window, and put the logic inside the loop. I know it is slow, but I have no idea if there is a better way to do this.

BTW, the same question is asked by other people:
[Sliding window iterator using rolling in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509107/sliding-window-iterator-using-rolling-in-pandas)

[Why doesn't my pandas rolling().apply() work when the series contains collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723003/why-doesnt-my-pandas-rolling-apply-work-when-the-series-contains-collection)