# Pandas: Can you access rolling window items

Tags: python, pandas

Can you access pandas rolling window object.

```
rs = pd.Series(range(10))
rs.rolling(window = 3)

#print's 
Rolling [window=3,center=False,axis=0]
```

Can I get as groups?:

```
[0,1,2]
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38510101/2336654

Comment: I'm of the opinion that what you want is intuitive.  It just hasn't been developed yet.

Comment: Any updates since last year? (still not developed?)

Comment: @Ziofil problem is solved in pandas `1.1` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65216213/2782049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround, but waiting to see if anyone has pandas solution:

```
def rolling_window(a, step):
    shape   = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - step + 1, step)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

rolling_window(rs, 3)

array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Answer (score 5):

I will start off this by saying this is reaching [into the internal impl](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx). But if you really really wanted to compute the indexers the same way as pandas.

You will need v0.19.0rc1 (just about released), you can `conda install -c pandas pandas=0.19.0rc1`

```
In [41]: rs = pd.Series(range(10))

In [42]: rs
Out[42]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64

# this reaches into an internal implementation
# the first 3 is the window, then second the minimum periods we
# need    
In [43]: start, end, _, _, _, _ = pandas._window.get_window_indexer(rs.values,3,3,None,use_mock=False)

# starting index
In [44]: start
Out[44]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

# ending index
In [45]: end
Out[45]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

# windo size
In [3]: end-start
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

# the indexers
In [47]: [np.arange(s, e) for s, e in zip(start, end)]
Out[47]: 
[array([0]),
 array([0, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([2, 3, 4]),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([4, 5, 6]),
 array([5, 6, 7]),
 array([6, 7, 8]),
 array([7, 8, 9])]
```

So this is sort of trivial in the fixed window case, this becomes extremely useful in a variable window scenario, e.g. in 0.19.0 you can specify things like `2S` for example to aggregate by-time.

All of that said, getting these indexers is not particularly useful. you generally want to *do* something with the results. That is the point of the aggregation functions, or `.apply` if you want to generically aggregate.

Comment: I love this idea, but I can't get the call to `pd._window.get_window_indexer()` to work. I keep getting `module 'pandas' has no attribute '_window'`. Any idea how to get around this? Also adding a link to the source for `get_window_indexer()` since its documentation won't show up in my notebook.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved in pandas `1.1`, as the rolling object is now an iterable:

```
[window.tolist() for window in rs.rolling(window=3) if len(window) == 3]
```